# How to restrict a type in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, oop, inheritance, types

In Delphi I can do this:

```
type
    TAnimal = class
        Name: String;
        constructor Create(const Name: String);
    end;

    TAnimalType = class of TAnimal;

    TElephant = class(TAnimal);

    TEmu = class(TAnimal);

    THovercraft = class;

implementation

var
    Zoo: TObjectList;

procedure PopulateZoo;
begin
    Zoo := TObjectList.Create(True);
    AddToZoo(TElephant, "Ellie");
    AddToZoo(TEmu, "Erik");
    AddToZoo(THovercraft, "Helen"); //Compiler error here
end;

procedure AddToZoo(AnimalType: TAnimalType; Name: String)
var
    Animal: TAnimal;
begin
    Animal := AnimalType.Create(Name);
    Zoo.Add(Animal);
end;
```

The code fails to compile because THovercraft does not inherit from TAnimal. If `AddToZoo(THovercraft);` is removed then the code will compile. Running it and calling PopulateZoo will create a list containing an instance of TElephant and an instance of TEmu.

How can I create this behaviour in C#? Key features that I want are

1) that the compiler forces AddToZoo to take only TAnimal and its descendants as its first parameter, and

2) that in AddToZoo I can easily call the constructor declared in TAnimal.

*P.S. This code is simplified to demonstrate my question.*

Comment: Show us the C# code you already have (without the restriction you're asking for).

Comment: C# has no concept of metaclass and so there's no compile time way to achieve the exact same. No way in C# to instantiate using a metaclass either. So nothing like `AnimalType.Create`. Which incidentally needs a virtual constructor. You should stop trying to use a literal port and instead write the code in C# using the capabilities that it offers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "write the code in C# using the capabilities that it offers" - That's what I'm asking for help with. I'm not asking for a literal port.

Comment: @cja There are no metaclasses in C#. You'll need a different solution to your problem then.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok, care to provide one? Else stop teasing me with comments :)

Comment: @cja I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: Please add comments to explain down votes

Answer (score 4):

What you want is "almost" possible in C#. You can use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) and [type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/d5x73970.aspx) to get that behavior:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Elephant : Animal {}
public class Emu : Animal {}
public class Hovecraft {}

public class Test
{
    private List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

    private void AddToZoo<T>(string name)
        where T : Animal, new()
    {
        var animal = new T();
        animal.Name = name;
        this.animals.Add(animal);
    }

    public void PopulateZoo()
    {
        this.AddToZoo<Elephant>("Ellie");
        this.AddToZoo<Enu>("Erik");
        this.AddToZoo<Hovercraft>("Whatever");  // Compiler error
    }
}
```

What you can't do in C# is using type constraints while having no default constructor; using the `new` keyword with type constraints [requires you to use a default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx). You can work around this by adding an `Initialize` method to your base class:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Initialize(string name) { this.Name = name; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var animal = new T();
animal.Initialize(name);
this.animals.Add(animal);
```

If you don't want to use type constraints, you can still pass around `Type` objects at runtime and use the `Activator` to create your instances, using Reflection:

```
var animalType = typeof(Emu);

if (!typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(animalType)) throw new Exception("Bummer.");
var animal = (Animal)Activator.CreateInstance(animalType);
// use animal
```

Comment: Please can you add the constructor with the Name parameter to the Animal class and then call it in AddToZoo?

Comment: This is better, but forces types to be determined at compile time. I know that they are in the Q, but in any real world scenarios the type is likely to be determined at runtime. I expect that the asker hasn't yet realised this nuance.

Comment: @cja That's not possible. You can only constrain `TAnimal` to have a parameterless constructor (with the `new()` constraint in the method signature). You can't force `TAnimal` to have an arbitrary constructor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why did you rename TAnimal to T in this answer? (You should add an edit summary when you edit.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why not TAnimal?

Comment: It's not very C#, it's easy to confuse with `Animal`, it's not the same as `TAnimal` in the Delphi code. Using plain `T` makes it easy to see that it is the generic parameter. At least that is if you are used to that naming convention. Which we all are.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Straight from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/12/02/497340.aspx - CONSIDER indicating constraints placed on a type parameter in the
name of the parameter.
For example, a parameter constrained to `ISession` might be called
`TSession`.

Comment: That article also endorses the use of `T`. I don't really mind. I just think that especially here where we have instances, classes, metaclasses, different languages, all mixed up, a bit of separation would aid the reader.

Comment: You could show an example using `CreateInstance` that called a constructor passing parameters. However, I seriously doubt that any of the above would be the right way to solve the underlying problem in C#. The problem is that the asker hasn't asked how to solve the underlying problem, rather he/she asked how to replicate the Delphi code in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of, is using generics ([Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)). With the type parameter constraints you can mimic the Delphi's type restriction you're mentioning.

```
class TAnimal {
    public TAnimal(string Name) { this.Name = Name; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Constructors cannot be inherited, so we have to implement it (calling
// the base class constructor) on each one of the derived classes.

class TElephant : TAnimal { public TElephant(string Name) : base(Name) { } }
class TEmu : TAnimal { public TEmu(string Name) : base(Name) { } }
class THovercraft { }

IList<object> Zoo = null;

void PopulateZoo() {
    Zoo = new List<object>();
    AddToZoo<TElephant>("Ellie");
    AddToZoo<TEmu>("Erik");
    AddToZoo<THovercraft>();
}

// Here, we specify the constraint [class TAnimal] for the type parameter T.

void AddToZoo<T>(string Name = null) where T: TAnimal {
    T Animal = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), Name);
    Zoo.Add(Animal);
}
```

If you try to compile it, you'll get the error message:

> The type 'UserQuery.THovercraft' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UserQuery.AddToZoo(string)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'UserQuery.THovercraft' to 'UserQuery.TAnimal'.

Tested it with [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) versión 4.

**NOTE:** *Didn't noticed Frank answered with the same approach.*